# Cannot access the the SSRS report through Reporting Action in the SSAS cube

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssas

I am trying to attach a SSRS report (data source is Oracle) to a cube

It is a straight Tabular report no parameters or anything. I deployed this report on the dev and tried to hook the report to the cube through "New Reporting Action". The settings are as described below:

1. Target Type: Cells
2. Target Object: All cells
3. ServerName: devport.com
4. Reportpath: /ReportLibrary/Sales/Report.rdl
5. ReportFormat: HTML3
6. Paramaters: None
7. Addtional Properties: None

After I process the cube when I access the cube from excel I can see the action but when I launch it I am getting an error in the Internet explorer browser which says my URL length is more than 260 but actually it is only 206 characters in length. In the URL when I replace the URL encoding %3f and % 26 with & the report launches just fine.

http://devport1.com/_layouts/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/reportlibrary/sales/report.rdl**%3F**%26rs:command=render**%26**rs:renderer=html3

Can anyone tell me what should I do so that I can make the report launch correctly in the browser.... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running in SharePoint integrated mode.  Your configuration should look something like this:

Server name: devport.com

Report path: /_vti_bin/reportserver?http://devport1.com/reportlibrary/sales/report.rdl

There is a good article on msdn about [URL Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153586.aspx) for SSRS in both standalone mode and in SharePoint integrated mode.